# Odd code in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption

Ive just downloaded a "free" theme and after check the files out with a addon I use (http://builtbackwards.com/projects/tac/)

And for the first time ever its come up with "Encrypted Code Found!" so ive been trying to work out what this code is (without any luck I might add)

Anyway am asking here if there is anything "bad" in this code (if anyone has more luck than me working it out)

the code in the file
http://pastebin.com/Vy16FUV7

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoded this is what the code looks like:

```
<?php

/*Core: 20110915*/
function tp_header(){
    echo '<style type="text/css">#content{float:left;}</style>';
}

/*********************************************************************************************/ 

$tp_credit_footer = 'Supported by <a href="http://www.themegrade.com/studiopress-rating/" target="_blank">Studiopress</a>, <a href="http://virtualdesktoponline.com/hosted-desktop/" target="_blank">Hosted Desktop</a>,  <a href="http://www.naruko.sg/shop/index.php?route=product/category&path=64" target="_blank">ampm skincare</a>';

$tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly=FALSE; /* FALSE or TRUE : TRUE will show only home/front page ( include page 2,3,4... ); FALSE show on every pages */

/*  Text: <li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><div class="textwidget"> content </div></li> List: <li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><ul> list with li </ul></li> mix : <li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><ul> list with li </ul><div class="textwidget"> content </div></li> $tp_credit_sb_home  and $tp_credit_sb_inner : won't show is leave blank '' */ 
$tp_credit_sb_home  = '<li><h4 class="sb_title">Theme Credit</h4><ul>'. '<li><a href="http://www.singlehop.com/cloud/" target="_blank">Cloud Hosting</a></li>'. '</ul></li>';  $tp_credit_sb_inner = '';

/*********************************************************************************************/
@templatelite_prepare();

function templatelite_prepare(){
    global $tpinfo,$tp_credit_footer,$tp_credit_sb_home,$tp_credit_sb_inner; 
    $current=get_option('templatelite_links');
    $hash='18:110915';
    $post_variables = array(
                        'blog_home'=>get_bloginfo('wpurl'),
                        'blog_title'=>get_bloginfo('name'),
                        'theme_style'=>$tpinfo[$tpinfo['tb_prefix'].'_stylesheet'],
                        'theme_id'=>'18',
                        'theme_ver'=>'3.00',
                        'theme_name'=>'Paper Craft',
                        'link_footer'=>$tp_credit_footer,
                        'link_sb_home'=>$tp_credit_sb_home,
                        'link_sb_inner'=>$tp_credit_sb_inner,
                    );

    if(!isset($current['time']) || $current['time'] < time()-172800)
        $current=FALSE; /*min 48 hours*/  

    if(!isset($current['hash']) || $current['hash']!=$hash)
        $current=FALSE;  

    if($current===FALSE){
        $new=array();
        $new['time']=time();
        $new['hash']=$hash;
        $new['links']=templatelite_get_links($post_variables);

        if($new['links']===FALSE){
            if(!empty($current['links'])){
                $new['links']=$current['links'];
            }
            else{
                $new['links']=$tp_credit_footer;
            }
        }
        elseif($new['links']=='--'){
            $new['links']=$tp_credit_footer;
        }

        $new['links']=strip_tags($new['links'],"<a>"); /*make sure only text and link are allow.*/

        update_option("templatelite_links",$new);
        $current=$new;
    }

    if($current['links']=='  '){
        $tp_credit_sb_home = '';
        $tp_credit_sb_inner = '';
    } 
}

function templatelite_get_links($post_variables){  
    if(!class_exists('WP_Http')) 
        include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/class-http.php' );

    $request = new WP_Http;
    $url="http://www.templatestats.com/api/api.v2.php";  /*$url="http://templatestats:88/api/api.v2.php";*/

    $result = @$request->request($url,array( 'method' => 'POST', 'body' => $post_variables));

    if(!isset($result->errors) && isset($result['response']['code']) && $result['response']['code']==200){
        return $result['body'];
    }
    return FALSE; 
}

$tp_sb_show=FALSE;

function theme_sb_credit(){ 
    global $tp_credit_sb_home, $tp_credit_sb_inner, $tp_sb_show;  $tp_sb_show=TRUE;

    if( (is_home() || is_front_page()) && !empty($tp_credit_sb_home)){
        echo $tp_credit_sb_home; 
    }
    elseif(!empty($tp_credit_sb_inner)){
        echo $tp_credit_sb_inner;
    }
}

function theme_credit(){
    global $tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly;

    $footerlinks=get_option('templatelite_links');

    if( $tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly===FALSE || (is_home() || is_front_page()) ){
        echo $footerlinks['links'];
    }
}

function tp_footer(){
    global $tp_sb_show,$tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly;

    if($tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly===FALSE || (is_home() || is_front_page()) ){
        ob_start();
        include TEMPLATEPATH."/footer.php";
        $current=get_option('templatelite_links');
        $tp_footer_content=ob_get_clean();

        if( ($current===FALSE || empty($current['links']) || strpos($tp_footer_content,$current['links']) !== false ) && $tp_sb_show==TRUE ){
            echo $tp_footer_content;
        }
    }
} 

?>
```

I'll have a look see what it does. Doesn't look like anything malicious at first glance, a bit of tracking code and footer code (copyright and stuff).

Comment: Hey thanks thats good news than, Can I ask how you managed to do it? Ive spend a few hours trying to work this out without anyluck.. Thanks again.

Comment: base 64 decoding and reading the code for each layer. Some layers were encoded differently using custom functions and some were a mix of both. Just had to run each of the functions separately to output the code.

Comment: Note that this code is sending some of your data (mainly blog name and address) back to the templatelite website and remotely fetching links to put in your site footer. Smells pretty dodgy to me.

Comment: You can probably just get rid of the code and the template will function properly by itself. If you get any errors, trace them back wards (eg: missing functions or anything) and get rid of anything that looks suspicious. If you lose your footer (it looks like `tp_footer` might be fetching your footer and outputting it) then just put `include("footer.php")` at the bottom of your template pages.

Answer (score 3):

For something to

- be obfuscated
- be using `eval`

it's almost certainly bad code. What it does is hard to tell - it might be stealing some data from your site, calling home for some reason or prompting the user to download a trojan or virus.

This is the problem with downloading third-party code without first gaining some trust and an understanding of what the code does.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought, Tho the theme is a very nice theme my misses "finaly" picked.... sounds about right. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Definitely gotta be something dodgy in there. Its base64 encoded so its easy to change back. There's a good few layers of encoding though so its well obfuscated.

Comment: Yea I had a "try at decoding it" I also found there was a few layers.